# Append prediction of tensorflow to a pandas dataframe

Tags: tensorflow, pandas, prediction, dataframe

I built a tensorflow model to make text classification in four category, after testing and evaluating it, I need to apply it to actual data to predict the class of them, I create a predict function that return the probability of each class that this text can be.
I read my data and apply prediction function using pandas.

```
df.apply(lambda x: predict(x['text']), axis=1)
```

what I need is to append predictions value to my original data frame such as:

```
text        class1_prob.   class2_prob     class3_prob     class4_prob
------      ------------   -----------     ------------     -----------  
1st string  0.1            0.2              0.4             0.3
```

How can I achieve that if my prediction function return probabilities for one string as:

```
[[0.1 0.2 0.4 0.3]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching I found a way by use pd.concatenate to concatenate the predictions dataframe with original data frame

```
predictions = df.apply(lambda x: predict(x['text']), axis=1)
predictions_df = pd.DataFrame(predictions.tolist(), columns=\ 
['class1_prob', 'class2_prob', 'class3_prob', 'class4_prob'])
df = pd.concat([df, predictions_df], axis=1)
```